# Android how to put two layouts below?

Tags: android, layout

I developed an app six months ago and now i try to update it. (Android studio updated). I create a new activity and I try to put two layout below (it could be relative layout or linear) but it doesn't work. I check my old project I used fill parent property but I can't use it now because of update.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_launcer_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_launcer_screen"
    android:elevation="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"></LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean match_parent?

Comment: Please provide code?

Comment: I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly you need?

Comment: this will create layout same way as you showed in image 3.

Comment: but every time do i need to write code i mean how can i do it with interface.

Comment: what exactly you need

Comment: If above code worked for you can you please accept my answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128958/discussion-between-vishal-sanghani-and-user2265473).

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`  remove this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_first"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_first">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```